# await promise return undefined?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, ecmascript-2017

#### Here is code :

```
export const wxreq = (config) => {
config.url = `${HTTP_HOST}${config.url}`;
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return wepy.request(Object.assign(config, {
        async success (res) {
            // res is a promise, this promise is return  {data: 123}
            const responseFromMiddle = await res;
            return resolve(responseFromMiddle.data);
        },
        fail () {
            reject(new Error(`Request ${config.url} fail!`));
        },
        complete () {
            resolve();
        }
    }))
  })
};
```

in vuejs life-cycle

```
async onReady () {
  cosnt res = wxreq(someCorrectConfig);
  console.log(res); // undefined; need to be 123 
}
```

I'm very curious that why res is not defined？ please help~  so confused！ thx~

Comment: Does your code really say `cosnt`? That might be a problem.

Comment: By definition, `resolve()` in your `complete` handler will set the resolved value in the returned promise to `undefined`.  If that gets called before the `success` handler, then the promise value will be latched to that.  If you want the promise to have a value, then do `resolve(someValue)`.  Personally, I don't see why you're resolving in `complete` at all.

Comment: Also, why `await res`?  You use `await` on a promise.  Is `res` a promise?  I doubt it.  If `res` is the result you want, then just do `resolve(res.data)`.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the `wepy` library so we can see how it works.  It seems extremely odd that a success callback would take a promise.  That is simply not how one would design an API with promises.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that whatever `wepy` is, it does not pass a promise to a `success` callback.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to problem with implementation.
To Call the wxreq you need to use await before that. Also wrap that condition inside a try block to catch ant exceptions.

```
async onReady () {
  try {
      const res = await wxreq(someCorrectConfig);
      console.log(res); // undefined; need to be 123 
    }
    catch(err){
    console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: use `await` before async operation in `async` function

```
async onReady () {
  const res = await wxreq(someCorrectConfig);
  console.log(res); // undefined; need to be 123 
}
```

and remove `return` in promise

```
export const wxreq = (config) => {
config.url = `${HTTP_HOST}${config.url}`;
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     wepy.request(Object.assign(config, {
        async success (res) {
            // res is a promise, this promise is return  {data: 123}
            const responseFromMiddle = await res;
            return resolve(responseFromMiddle.data);
        },
        fail () {
            reject(new Error(`Request ${config.url} fail!`));
        },
        complete () {
            resolve();
        }
    }))
  })
};
```

Comment: Thx!  Sry, I made a mistake with my questionable code , truth is that I did it like you , still have problem. I found that wxreq(someCorrectConfig) return a promise object, has _value attribute, is always undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do

```
export async function wxreq(config) {
    const res = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        wepy.request(Object.assign(config, {
            url: `${HTTP_HOST}${config.url}`,
            success: resolve,
            fail: reject
        });
    });
    return res.data;
}
```

but it is hard to say without knowing what `wepy` is.